# Airflow dag dependencies

Tags: airflow

I have a airflow dag-1 that runs approximately for week and dag-2 that runs every day for few hours. When the dag-1 is running i cannot have the dag-2 running due to API limit rate (also dag-2 is supposed to run once dag-1 is finished).
Suppose the dag-1 is running already, then dag-2 that is supposed to run everyday fails, is there a way i can schedule the dag dependencies in a right way?
Is it possible to stop dag-1 temporarily(while running) when dag-2 is supposed to start and then run dag-1 again without manual interruption?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way is to use the defined pool ..

Lets say if you have a pool named: "specefic_pool" and allocate only one slot for it.

Specify the pool name in your dag bash command (instead of default pool, please use newly created pool) By that way you may over come of running both the dags parallel .

This helps whenever Dag1 is running Dag2 will never be triggered until pool is free or if the dag2 picked the pool until dag2 is completed dag1 is not going to get triggered.